# Get rows with unique indexes DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I format excel file by removing some rows with invalid data. I'm trying to save removed data to a new DataFrame.
I created a copy of original DataFrame and would like to compare them. Rows that are missing in my output DataFrame should be written to a new DF.

```
path = 'Users/Files/Directory-All.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df2 = pd.read_excel(path)

format_data(df):
   pass
df = format_data(df)
```

So, how can I get removed rows by comparing indexes of df and df2?

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I got it.

```
indexes = [x for x in df2.index if x not in df.index]
df2.iloc[indexes]
```